# Node Js make call to http python flask server

Tags: python, node.js, flask, httpbackend

I have a machine learning model, I have made an API out of it, and hosted a flask server to make it accessible as such

```
server = '192.168.71.53'
port = 5000

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/get_faces":{"origins":"http://"+server+":"+str(port)}})

@app.route('/call_method', methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin(origin=server, headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def call_model():
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host=server, port=port )
```

I then created a front end in Node JS that posts a request to this method via the server and IP using this

```
axios.post('http://192.168.71.53:5000/call_method', dataJson)
            .then(response => {
                # process data }  }  })
```

The program runs fine on localhost, i ran into an issue when running the website on an ip, chrome won't let me access the camera in Node Js if i don't have a HTTPS connection, so i deployed the website on a link, and tried to access it, the camera works now but it won't post a request to my flask server, i looked into it and i read that HTTPS cant make call to HTTP, so i set up flask to HTTPS via using this

```
context = ('certificate.pem', 'key.pem')
app.run(host=server, port=port , ssl_context=context)
```

Now whenever i post a request, chrome gives a `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error

so i decided to post a http request rather than https request, for that i had to add this to my html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

this gives me a `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error on chrome and `code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -` error on flask

I have tried several other things and nothing seems to work, can someone please help me out with this? I have been struggling with this for well over 2 weeks now

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different things going on here. Let's try and break them down.

1. Firstly, your app needs to run on HTTPS securely to be allowed
   camera permissions as you have discovered. While developing your
   app, if you host it on localhost and access it through a
   http://localhost:port url, then you can still access camera
   permissions *without* HTTPS. This is a concession made only for the
   localhost to make developing easier.
2. On to the next part with flask and HTTPS. From the looks of it, you
   generated a certificate and passed that on to flask to serve HTTPS
   traffic. This did not work because you used a self-signed
   certificate. A self-signed certificate as the name implies is 
   signed by an individual (you) and cannot be used to verify a web
   server's identity. Thish is why you got the
   `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. Chrome is telling you that
   it does not recogonise the Certificate Authority (you) who signed
   the certificate.

   The fix for this again is to just run everything on localhost for development. You do not have to worry about HTTPS before you are ready to deploy your code.
3. Why did you have to add this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`
   to make an http post request? 
   This tells the browser to upgrade a HTTP connection to a HTTPS connection. So when your js code sent a HTTP POST request, this meta tag upgraded that connection to HTTPS, which then failed with net:ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR because flask was no longer listening with HTTPS enabled. Flask threw a 400 protocol error because chrome tried to upgrade its HTTP connection to a HTTPS connection which flask did not understand.

In summation, run everything on localhost and you will not need to mess about with HTTPS until you really need to.

Comment: i actually need to deploy it, so i can test it, what can i do in this case? the deployment is not actual deployment, i am deploying it for testing purposes, any way to bypass this?

Comment: Also as far as i know, the certificate isn't self signed, we have affiliated it with a domain name, still the issue persists

Comment: There are two certificates here. One is for the node server and the other is for the flask server. They both have to be valid. Please check if the flask cert is self-signed.

Comment: The only way to bypass the HTTPS restrictions are, like I said to run it on localhost or run both with valid certs. If both certs are valid and the servers are hosted on those valid domains, then you are fine. As in, if your certs are for foo.example.com and bar.example.com, then your servers must be hosted at foo.example.com and bar.example.com with the correct cert loaded for that domain.

Comment: i am very new at this so forgive my ignorance, but i have the following certs, a .pem certificate, 3 .csr .key .crt certificates and two certificate.pem and private_key.pem, i use these to deploy the website and to host the flask server, the website is available at the link and it works just fine, so i think the certificates are valid, and since i use those certificates to host the server, they too shoulf work right?

Comment: Certificates contain a public key and a private key. They can be packaged in many different file formats like .pem, .key, etc. A .csr file is a certificate signing request file. That file is made by the requester of the certificate (maybe you) and sent to the Certificate Authority (CA) who will then return your certficiate in any one of a number of formats: .pem, .key, .crt, etc. Now you need a public key and a private key for each of your domains. Your servers need to be on different domains and your certificates have to be for those specific domains. Is this helping?

Comment: So i guess our certificate is signed, which of these can i use to host my flask server, any should do right?

Comment: Yeah either one will work. The certificate has to be for the domain that the server is hosted on. This bit is important. Let me rephrase. The domain on your cert has to match up to the one flask is listening on.

Comment: Hmm, i understand now, alright ill have a look, thanks alot for your help :) if this helps me solve the problem ill be sure to accept the answer

Comment: No worries. Slow day at work so, I'm messing about on SO.

Comment: productive messing around i suppose :P